# useState, useEffect and fetch not working together

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, fetch-api

I made a page that calls an API and shows the data on UI. Here are the parts of the code:

```
const HomeGo = ({route}) => {
    const token = route.params.token
    const message = route.params.message
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [foodSizeValue, setFoodSizeValue] = useState('');
    const [foodSizeValues, setFoodSizeValues] = useState([
    {label: 'X Small', value: 'XS'},
    {label: 'Small', value: 'S'},
    {label: 'Medium', value: 'M'},
    {label: 'Large', value: 'L'},
    {label: 'X Large', value: 'XL'}
  ]);

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [days, setDays] = useState([]);
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
  const [menuItem, setMenuItem] = useState({});
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('#E3E3E3');
  const [mainCourse, setMainCourse] = useState('');
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState('');
  const [currMenuObj, setCurrMenuObj] = useState('')
  const [isNoCarbsSelected, setNoCarbsSelection] = useState(false);
  
  const horizTabArr = []

  useEffect(effectFunction = () => {
    console.log("useEffect")

    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log('Fetching data ...')
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {  'Set-Cookie' : token }
      };
  
      const resp = await fetch("http://someapi.com?date=&offset=0", requestOptions);
      const data = await resp.json();
      let detailsData = data.data
      var dateToday = new DateObject();
      setCurrentMonth(Moment(dateToday).format('MMM'))
      var dateTodayInFormat = Moment(dateToday).format('ddd, DD');
      let currentDayIdx = 0;
      console.log("detailsData ", detailsData);
  
      
      for(let i = 0; i < detailsData.length; i++) {
  
        const dayDtDt = Moment(detailsData[i].date).format('ddd, DD');
        if(dayDtDt == dateTodayInFormat) {
          currentDayIdx = i;
        }
        menuItem[dayDtDt] = detailsData[i];
  
        const dayDtDay = Moment(detailsData[i].date).format('ddd');
        const dayDt = '{"day":"'.concat(dayDtDay).concat('","date":"'.concat(dayDtDt).concat('"}'));
        days.push(JSON.parse(dayDt));
  
        let topRadius = 0, bottomRadius = 0;
        
        if(i == detailsData.length - 1) {
          bottomRadius = 5
        }
        let initialArrCurr = '{"id":'.concat(i).concat(',"color":"#e3e3e3","text":"'.concat(dayDtDt).concat('","topRadius":'.concat(topRadius).concat(',"bottomRadius":'.concat(bottomRadius).concat('}'))))
        console.log(initialArrCurr)
        horizTabArr.push(JSON.parse(initialArrCurr))
      }
  
      horizTabArr[currentDayIdx].color = 'white'; // default day  
      console.log(menuItem[horizTabArr[currentDayIdx].text]) // PRINTS CORRECT VALUE <-------
      setCurrMenuObj(menuItem[horizTabArr[currentDayIdx].text])
      console.log("currMenuObj ", currMenuObj); // PRINTS NULL <-------
      setFoodSizeValue(currMenuObj.size)
      console.log("foodSizeValue ", foodSizeValue) // PRINTS EMPTY <-------
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
    console.log("currMenuObj 3 ", currMenuObj);
  }, []);

const [buttonData, setButtonData] = useState(horizTabArr)

const changeColorB2 = (buttonInfo, index) =>(e) => {
    let newArrray = [] // You have to create a new object and set it for react to re-render
    for(let i = 0; i < buttonData.length; i++) {
      newArrray.push(buttonData[i])
      newArrray[i].color = '#e3e3e3'
    }
    newArrray[index].color = 'white'
    setCurrMenuObj(menuItem[newArrray[index].text])
    setFoodSizeValue(menuItem[newArrray[index].text].size)
    setButtonData(newArrray);
}

  const buttonsListArr = buttonData.map((buttonInfo, index) => 
  (
    <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:buttonInfo.color,flex:1, padding: 15, borderTopLeftRadius:buttonInfo.topRadius, borderBottomLeftRadius:buttonInfo.bottomRadius,justifyContent:'center'}} 
    onPress={changeColorB2(buttonInfo, index)} key={buttonInfo.id}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:10}}>{buttonInfo.text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ));

  const onPress = () => {

  }
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'column', flex:1}}>
             <View style={{flex:2}}>
                <Image source={require('./images/image-450x180.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}/>
             </View>
             <View style={{flex:0.5, width:'90%', alignSelf:'center'}}>
                <Text style={{position:'absolute', bottom:0, right:5, fontSize: 18, fontFamily:'Futura'}}>{message}</Text>
             </View>
             <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flex:4.5, width:'90%', alignSelf:'center', marginTop:10}}>
                 <View style={{flex:1, marginRight: -1}}>
                 <View style={{backgroundColor:'purple', flex:1, padding: 15, borderTopLeftRadius:5, justifyContent:'center'}}>
                          <Text style={{fontSize:15, fontWeight:'bold', color:'white'}}>{currentMonth}</Text>
                  </View>
                    {buttonsListArr}
                 </View>
                 <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', flex:5, borderTopRightRadius:10, borderBottomRightRadius:10}}>
                    <View style={{marginTop:20}}>
                      <Text style={{textAlign:'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18}}>{currMenuObj.details}</Text>
                      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', zIndex:1, alignSelf:'center'}}>
                         <Text style={{ fontSize: 18}}>Size / Count   </Text>
                        <DropDownPicker placeholder='Size' containerStyle={{width: 100}} style={{zIndex:999}} open={open} value={foodSizeValue} items={foodSizeValues} setOpen={setOpen} setValue={setFoodSizeValue} setItems={setFoodSizeValues}/>
                      </View>
                      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                         <Checkbox value={isNoCarbsSelected} onValueChange={setNoCarbsSelection}/>
                         <Text style={{textAlign:'center', fontSize: 18, width:'35%'}}>No rice / bread</Text>
                      </View>
                      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={currMenuObj.readonly == 1 ? styles.buttonDisabled : styles.button} onPress={onPress} disabled={currMenuObj.readonly == 1}>
                            <Text style={{color:'white'}}>RSVP</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </View>
                      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <Text style={{flex:1, textAlign:'center', color:'blue'}}>Special Instructions</Text>
                        <Text style={{flex:1, textAlign:'center', color:'blue'}}>Provide Feedback</Text>
                      </View>
                      <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                        <Text style={{flex:1, textAlign:'center', color:'blue'}}>{'<<'} Prev week</Text>
                        <Text style={{flex:1, textAlign:'center', color:'blue'}}>Next week {'>>'}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                 </View>
             </View>
             <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
        </View>
      
    );

}
```

As recommended everywhere, I am using useEffect already but still the setters don't take effect (See <------- above). What am I doing wrong? (I referred to [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fetching-data-updating-state-hooks) amongst many others.)

Comment: "setState is asynchronous call means if synchronous call get called it may not get updated at right time like to know current value of object after update using setState it may not get give current updated value on console" - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-setstate/amp/

Comment: If you put your console.log statements outside the useEffect hook (but still in the component), you will see them be triggered every time you render the component. This will show you how the state updates asynchronously.

Comment: @Konrad I had read that a few times and it's not making sense to me. If values are updated on next render what if I need them in current render. For example, I want to enhance this code so that I have a button onPress of which I add 7 to offset and call the same API again with http://someapi.com?date=&offset=7 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`useState` is asynchronous. You set the variable and check it again on the same render, so it's not updated.

I recommencement using the `useEffect` hook to check whether or not state is updated.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    // You see updated values here.
}, [currentMonth, foodSizeValue])
```